# Simple imperative linked list

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

I've decided to learn a bit of C++, and so I've started with a simple linked list. There's no input to the program and should always output `hlo`. This is as in `main` I build a list consisting of `hello`, and use `Get` and `last` to get the data.

I don't know C++, or C, and so this is mostly a stab in the dark. I don't know if I'm using C++ correctly, but I got a working program where I'm mostly exploring pointers, so I would like to know if my usage for them is correct. Otherwise please review any and all aspects of my code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    Node(char data_) {
        data = data_;
    }

    Node *next = NULL;
    char data;
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node *root = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
    LinkedList() {}

    void Add(char data) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = new Node(data);
            last = root;
        } else {
            last->next = new Node(data);
            last = last->next;
        }
    }

    char Get(int index) {
        return _Get(index)->data;
    }
private:
    Node* _Get(int index) {
        Node *node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (node == NULL) {
                throw std::out_of_range("List doesn't contain that item.");
            }
            node = node->next;
        }
        return node;
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList list = LinkedList();
    list.Add('h');
    list.Add('e');
    list.Add('l');
    list.Add('l');
    list.Add('o');
    std::cout << list.Get(0) << list.Get(2) << list.last->data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `_Get` is a reserved identifier. See: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065) Prefer not to use `_` in C++ identifiers. If you must don't use them at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Memory Leak

Your code leaks. I see calls to `new` but I see no smart pointers or calls to delete to reclaim the memory. You need a destructor on your linked list.

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList()  {}
    ~LinkedList() {/* Reclaim dynamically allocated memory here */}
};
```

#### Rule of three

Once you correct for memory management you also realize that you are violating the rule of three. By default the compiler will automatically add copy constructor and assignment opertors for you.

```
LinkedList   a;
a.add('x');
LinkedList   b(a);   // Makes a copy of a
                     // But only a shallow copy.
a.add('y');
// This changes 'a' to be {'x', 'y}
// Problem is that b is now also {'x', 'y} 
// **BUT** in b last points at the wrong node.

// Now things get interesting:
b.add('z');
// Now a and b are {'x', 'z'} (if you follow from root)
// a.last still points {'y'} even though this is no longer
// in the chain pointed to from a.root
```

The default implementation of the copy constructor (and assignment operator) is to make a shallow copy of the members. This fine as long as your members are not owned pointers. But your pointers are owned (even though you missed the deletion). So you either need to implement the copy semantics of the class or explicitly remove these methods.

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList()  {}
    ~LinkedList() {/* Reclaim dynamically allocated memory here */}
    LinkedList(LinkedList const&)            = delete;
    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList const&) = delete;
};
```

#### Prefer nullptr

In C++11 we introduced `nullptr` to replace `NULL`. This is because `NULL` is the integer zero and can accidentally be converted to an integer type without any warning. `nullptr` on the other hand has a type of `std::nullptr_t` and can only be converted to pointer types (not integers).

#### Design.

When building linked lists I prefer to use a `Sentinel` object. This removes the need for checking for `null` in your list and thus makes the code easier to write and understand. There are a lot of C++ code reviews on linked lists where I explain the principle.

#### Node should be private

You declare `Node` publicly. There is no reason for people to know the implementation details of your linked list. Make this a private member of `LinkedList` so show that this is an implementation detail.

#### Prefer to use initializer list:

```
    Node(char data_) {
        data = data_;
    }

    // Prefer to write like this:

    Node(char data_)
        :data(data_)
    {}
```

For non pod types this is because the object are constructed before the body of the constructor is entered then the constructor code is applied. If `data` was a non pod object that means you would first be constructing it and then applying the assignment operator (ie initializing it twice).

For pod data it makes no difference, **BUT** does no harm either. So it is a good habit to get into. Because that way of the code is later modified to be a non pod type (i.e. CharUTF) then doing it the prefered way keeps the code optimal.

#### Not a fan

```
    Node *root = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
```

Personally I like to see all the members initialized in the initializer list. But I can see some advantages for objects with lots of constructors in avoiding writing the same thing repeatedly.

#### Style Check.

Most style guides for C++ (though this is not ubiquitous so just take as advice and not a rule). User defined types have an initial capital letter, while objects (which includes functions/methods) have an initial lowercase letter.

This is because the **most** important thing in C++ is the types. So it is useful to be able to quickly identify types from objects.

```
    void Add(char data) {
    // I would prefer
    void add(char data) {
```

#### Self Documenting code

Personally I don't like `add()` as the name of the function. It does not tell me exactly what the function does. I think a better name would be `append()`.

#### Dont' use `_` in identifers.

The rules on using underscore are non trivial. Even if you know them. Other people don't know them as well as they think they do. So best to avoid to prevent accidental mistakes.

```
    Node* _Get(int index) { // Note this is a reserved identifier.
                            // And being a common word is very likely
                            // to be used somewhere. including the
                            // wrong header file before this is likely
                            // to generate some confusing error messages
                            // on some systems.

    // Why Note
    Node* getNode(int index)
```

#### Bug

```
 LinkedList  a;
 a.Add('a');
 a.Get(1); // Undefined behavior.
           // I believe _Get() is going to return a `nullptr`
           // which is then dereferenced by Get()
```

#### Declaring variables

```
    LinkedList list = LinkedList();
                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^  Creates a temporary object.
```

Technically this is creating a `LinkedList` temporary object then calling the copy constructor of `list` to copy the temporary object then destroying the temporary object.

Fortunately most compilers will spot this and optimize out the copy and destruction and just create your object.

But this is simpler to declare as:

```
    LinkedList list;
```

#### Prefer `\n` to std::endl;

The only difference is that `std::endl` performs an extra flush. Forcing a manual flush is usually never the correct solution as the libraries will do this for you when required.

#### Main and return

The `main()` function is special. If the compiler detects there is no return it will plant one for you.

```
    return 0;
```

So there is no need to add it yourself. It is become standard that when main can return no other value than `0` that the `return 0` is omitted to indicate that the application can never fail. So when I see a `return 0` at then end I generally look around for the other situations where it can fail. So if there are potentially failure situations and you exit early with an `return 1;` then add a `return 0;` and then end otherwise don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

For the beginner, and given the scope of the program, looks good. Few remarks.

- **`NULL`** is frowned upon. A politically correct `NULL` is `nullptr`.
- **`void Add(char data)`**

  After the call, the newly added node becomes a last node, no matter what. You better make this explicit. I also recommend to document the invariant with assertion:

  ```
  void Add(char data)
  {
      Node * n = new Node(data);
      if (root == nullptr) {
          assert(last == nullptr);
          root = n;
      } else {
          assert(last != nullptr);
          last->next = n;
      }
      last = n;
  }
  ```
- **`Node(char data)`**

  - <strike>`next` is undefined. Set it to `nullptr` explicitly.</strike>
  - C++ allows a cute shortcut `Node(char data): data(data), next(nullptr) {}`
- Exposing `next` to public hardly has a reason. With it exposed, client is free to violate all invariants. To let a client iterate over the list, provide an iterator.
- I don't see the point of delegating `Get` to a private member.

Comment: "`next` is undefined" No it's not, look at the declaration of `next`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Point taken, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I see some opportunities for improvement, which will get this up to about what we expect from a `LinkedList`.  First, the imposition that the stored elements are `char` is not optimal.  Sooner or later you will want non-`char` elements, and you will not want to write and maintain another `LinkedList` for each data type you want.  `char` is, in fact, the least useful element type I can think of.  The solution is a `template` class; instance objects would be declared `LinkedList <whateverType >`; a programmer will expect this syntax and the reusabilty it produces.

Second, there should be no `add` method as it is unclear where the new element is added.  Instead, we expect methods like `insert(int index, T element)` for O(`index`) insertion at `index` and O(N) `append` for what you are currently doing with `add`.

Third, you may recognize your `add` as being O(k); this is because you've actually written a queue (with minimal modification, a deque), which extends a real `LinkedList`.  A real `LinkedList` has no need of a tail pointer (`last` here).

Comment: Nice points, to be a pedant, I see `add` as \$O(1)\$ not as \$O(k)\$. But your points stand none the less. Thank you.